# Inherited a macro written in Microsoft VBA, trying to figure out why it's giving Runtime Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm working in an Excel spreadsheet that I inherited from my predecessor in my position and I have no experience whatsoever with VBA. The macro he created has an "Add Month" button to add monthly data to the spreadsheet, but when I click on it I get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". When attempting to debug, the code points me to a specific line. Problem is I have no idea what I'm looking at and why it's different from the other lines of code. The module is very repetitive, so I do not know why this SPECIFIC line of code is giving issues when other identical lines are not. I've included the code below, with the problem line bolded.

```
Sub NewMonth()
'
' NewMonth Macro
'
Dim calc As String
If Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic Then
    calc = "A"
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Else:
    calc = "M"
End If
'
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("L1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Range("L133").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    'Range("L132").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Range("L133").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    'Range("L132").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Range("L133").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    'Range("L132").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Range("L133").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    'Range("L132").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Range("L133").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    'Range("L132").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select '<-------- THIS LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR
    'Range("L133").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    'Range("L132").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("L1").Select
If calc = "A" Then Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

I tried a few basic troubleshooting recs like checking "Trust access to the VBA project object model" and searching for any GWXL97.XLA files but to no avail.

Any and all advice is appreciated!

Comment: Your predecessor also didn't had much experience with VBA. That said: *Which* line is throwing the error?

Comment: By clicking on "Debug" at the error window a line of the code will be highlighted, that is the line you should mark in the question to help understand the issue

Comment: if you place the code as code in a question, formatting is dismissed because a code rendering is active. Mark in another manner e.g. Inserting text with `'` sign, where you want to sign the relevant line.

Comment: The macro requires at least 6 groupings of lines , is that what you have ? Without them one of the `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` will select row 1048576 causing `Selection.Offset(1, 0)` to try to select a row off the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: Apologies I attempted to bold the problem line but that clearly didn't work, I've now marked the line that is throwing the error with a comment and arrow.

Comment: `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select` will fail if the selection is already at the bottom of the sheet - you can't offset from the last row.

Comment: Agree with `Tim`. There are multiple `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` clauses.  If `Selection` object is on the last data row. `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` will select the bottom worksheet row(s), then `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select` will fail.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it from trying to select the last row then? When I click the button to Add Month, the selection self-scrolls down the sheet until it hits the bottom and then throws the error. Near as I can figure the macro attempts to identify the most recent data row entry but then just jumps to the end of the sheet.

Comment: Without knowing what your worksheet looks like, it's difficult to give useful suggestions.  *In general* if you want to find the next empty row, the typical approach is to start from the bottom of the sheet - eg:  `Dim c As Range: Set c = Activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` should result in `c` referencing the cell below the last-used cell in Col A of the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning up the sheet

```vb
Sub NewMonth2()
    '
    ' NewMonth Macro
    '
    Dim bAuto As Boolean, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, n As Long
    Dim r As Long, lastRow As Long, firstcol As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    With Application
        bAuto = (.Calculation = xlAutomatic)
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
         .Columns("N:N").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
         firstcol = Cells(1, "L").Column
         lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
         For r = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            
            If Len(.Cells(r, "L")) = 0 Then
               ' skip
            ElseIf Len(.Cells(r + 1, "L")) = 0 Then
                ' empty cell below so last row of group
                lastcol = .Cells(r, "L").End(xlToRight).Column
                Set rng = .Cells(r, "L").Resize(1, 1 + lastcol - firstcol)
                rng.Copy
                rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                n = n + 1
                
                ' replace formula with values
                rng.Value2 = rng.Value2
    
            End If
         Next
        
        .Columns("N:N").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Cells(1, firstcol).Select
    
    End With
    With Application
        If bAuto Then .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    MsgBox lastRow & " rows scanned " & vbLf & _
           n & " rows inserted", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
```